# Load project from github

Tags: xcode

I read blog of Mike Ash, and in one of the article http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-02-08-lets-build-key-value-coding.html he give link to the project in github https://github.com/mikeash/MAObject. So I cann't load this project, I don't understand: maybe I need create special project and copy Mike's files to project? I always use projects with .xcodeproj files, so I didn't face with such problem

Comment: @ikinciviking: No; I think he's asking how to execute raw source

Comment: @SLaks, yean I don't understand how execute tester.m

Comment: You don't need to execute `tester.m`. It is a tester.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAObject is a class. Add the `.h` and `.m` file to an existing project.

Comment: I understand it, but I don't understand what I need do to execute tester.m

Comment: You don't need to. He's given you a class; just use it like you would use any class. `tester` just shows you the kinds of things you can say to this class.

Answer (score 0):

You can always clone a repository with `git clone [url]`

```
git clone https://github.com/mikeash/MAObject.git
```

Comment: Irrelevant. He knows how to get the files; he just doesn't understand what to do with them.